# How to put elements in the new line based on the screen size for flex-boxes?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simplified of my code structure:

```css
.parent{
  max-width:1100px;
  width:calc(100% - 4rem);
  display:flex;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  padding:10px 0px;
}

.child{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 0px 3px 15px 0px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 285px;
  max-width: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, child elements are all located horizontally next to each other. I need to remove `overflow-x:scroll;` and put them under each other. So, for a normal screen size, it would be 4 boxes next to each other and the next must go in the new line.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you consider a "normal" screen, phone, tablet, desktop, tv..?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

`.parent{display:flex;}` is the one who make all childs located horizontally next to each other

```css
.parent{
  max-width:1100px;
  padding:10px 0px;
}

.child{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 0px 3px 15px 0px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
  <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```